# Extend existing XSD in XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to write an application that exports some data as XML.
The XML my application should export is a given standard.
This standard allows to use DTD or XSD for validation. Because XSD is in my opinion the better way I use XSD.

But there is one challange. The standard allows the XML to extend that standard. In order to do that, the exported XML have to extend the standards XSD (or DTD).

For DTD you can do it like the following sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE ROOT "original_dtd_file.dtd"
[
<!ENTITY % USERDEFINES "(ELEMENT_ONE?,ELEMENT_TWO?)">
<!ELEMENT ELEMENT_ONE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ELEMENT_TWO (#PCDATA)>
]
>
```

Is this possible for XSD too?
To write a new XSD is not an option.

I tried to get a solution by searching the internet but I dont get any clues.

Edit: I think my question was not fully correct. One important point is, that the extension of the schema has to be written IN the exported XML. To write a second schema file with the extended schema is sadly not an option.

Thanks in advance!

André

Answer (score 1):

Yes, XSD is designed to support all the commonly used techniques for supporting DTD extension, and a few more.  The answer by helderdarocha sketches some of the methods.

What exactly you should do to extend the standard schema you are using depends on just how the standard to which you wish to conform allows you to extend the schema.  If the analogy with the DTD fragment you specify is exact, it seems likely that the base schema is written with wildcards to allow user-defined elements in appropriate places.  If that is so, then all you need to do is to define your new elements, preferably in your own namespace, and signal the location of both the standard schema and of your schema document to the validator.  Without knowing how the standard schema is written, or what the specification says about extension, it's impossible to be more precise.

If the standard schema is public, you may wish to provide a link to it, to allow people to examine it and see just what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly extend XSD. There's a lot you can do. XML Schema allows you to include XSDs of the same namespace, redefine types, import XSDs of different namespaces, for example.

If you have a XML instance like this:

```
<ROOT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="base.xsd">
    <ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_1>aaa</ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_1>
    <ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_2>bbb</ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_2>
</ROOT>
```

Validated by this XSD (`base.xsd`):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="ROOT" type="RootType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="RootType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

And you need to extend it to add two new elements in the `ROOT`, you can create a new schema where you redefine the type of the element, and declare new ones. For example, this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="base.xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="RootType">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="RootType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="ELEMENT_ONE" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element ref="ELEMENT_TWO" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:redefine>

    <xs:element name="ELEMENT_ONE" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="ELEMENT_TWO" type="xs:string"/>

</xs:schema>
```

will allow you to add `ELEMENT_ONE` and `ELEMENT_TWO` to a document which uses this XSD (`extended.xsd`) to validate it:

```
<ROOT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="extended.xsd">
    <ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_1>aaa</ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_1>
    <ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_2>bbb</ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_2>
    <ELEMENT_ONE>xxx</ELEMENT_ONE>
    <ELEMENT_TWO>yyy</ELEMENT_TWO>
</ROOT>
```

If you have different namespaces, you can use `xs:import` and reuse type definitions and elements to create new types, elements and attributes. You can also use `xs:include` to simply add types, elements and attributes from an existing schema to the new one.

**Update** - about inlining XSD

You asked about inline XSDs. They are supported but, as far as I know, that support is *non-standard* (but I might be wrong). From my experience I've noticed that while some parsers support them without any changes, others will fail complaining about `xs:schema` not being the outermost element, and some parsers will work with some adjustments.

If your parser supports it, it might be as simple as just placing the XSD inside the ROOT element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xs:redefine schemaLocation="base.xsd">
            <xs:complexType name="RootType">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="RootType">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="schema" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                            processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                            <xs:element ref="ELEMENT_ONE" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element ref="ELEMENT_TWO" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:redefine>
        <xs:element name="ELEMENT_ONE" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="ELEMENT_TWO" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:schema>
    <ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_1>aaa</ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_1>
    <ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_2>bbb</ORIGINAL_ELEMENT_2>
    <ELEMENT_ONE>xxx</ELEMENT_ONE>
    <ELEMENT_TWO>yyy</ELEMENT_TWO>
</ROOT>
```

That works in Microsoft parsers and in online services such as http://www.xmlvalidation.com.

Some parsers based on Apache XSV may not find your schema unless you add an `id='schemaName'` to your `xs:schema` element and then refer to it from your `ROOT` using the attribute `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="#schemaName"`.

A parser may also try to validate the entire document without skipping the `xs:schema` block. If that happens it will complain about a misplaced `xs:schema` element. You can fix that adding a declaration for the `xs:schema` element in your `xs:sequence` (as shown in the code above).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. The point is, I need the extension of the schema wirtten in the exported XML file. See my questions edit for more.

Comment: I am not sure if that's supported as a XSD *standard*, but many (or most, perhaps) parsers support it. It might work simply including the XSD it in the document under `ROOT`, or it might require some adjustments in the schema and `xsi` attributes. I'll add an update with some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I will test it the next days and wirte my experience.